# Read data from CSV in PHP and then forward to a webpage

Tags: php, csv, header

I've to redirect my user to a webpage based on his name and date. If his name does not match or his ID has expired I need to send him to a different page. If he passes these two conditions I need to redirect him to a webpage eg. www.google.com

```
$name_value=$_GET['query'];
$fh = fopen('db.csv', 'r');
$now = date(); 
$data=fgetcsv($fh); 
$name=$data[0];
$date=$data[1];
$url=$data[2];
if($name_value == $name)
{
  if($date==$now)
  {
   header("Location:".$data[2]);
  }
}
else
  {
   echo("not successful");
  }
exit;
```

This is the CSV file contents

```
 merch,26.06.2011,http://www.google.com
```

My problem is that the Header is not redirecting to the webpage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that it's not redirecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

date(), without any arguments, produces this on my server:

```
Warning: date() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in test.php on line 1
```

I suggest you turn your error reporting on for testing purposes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
```

To match the format in your CSV file, you need:

```
$now = date("d.m.Y");
```

Answer (score 4):

First, are your warnings turned on? This should not be failing silently.

Second, you probably mean `date("m.d.Y");` and not `date();`.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty way of doing this would be using a [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to redirect to the desired site (but don't beat me :D ).

Also:

```
if($name_value == $name && $date==$now)
```

You don't need to use two if-statements. Bind the two conditions with a logical `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multiple users listed in this csv file? fgetcsv() only reads a single line at a time, so for multiple users you'd have to use a loop to first find the line that the user is on, THEN check the expiry date.

---

for multiple users, you'd need to do this:

```
$fh = fopen('db.csv', 'rb');
while(list($name, $date, $url) = fgetcsv($fh)) {
   if (($name === $name_value) && ($date === $now)) 
       header("Location: $url");
       exit();
   }
}
echo "not successful";
```

Comment: yes I do have multiple users in the list, so I must write a different code to read entire contents of the file then check for validity ? correct me if I am wrong

Comment: thanks for the code but since I will be declaring the values of the array list before using fgetcsv again will give me an error

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the Header location before you send any other content to the user; otherwise, the header doesn't redirect.

Comment: could you explain a bit more on it. How can I go about resolving it ?

Comment: @Vinner: put simply, perform your checks that involve a header redirect at the beginning of your PHP file, and don't output anything before the Header call.  You can use output buffering to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

You call `date()` without any parameters, which means `$date` is set to `false` and will only match `$now` values that can also be considered false.

> Returns a formatted date string. If a
> non-numeric value is used for
> timestamp, FALSE is returned and an
> E_WARNING level error is emitted.

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)